# UIView Buttons loaded with XIB do not work

Tags: iphone, class, uiview, xib

I've loaded a UIView (FirstView.m) with a separate XIB (SecondView.xib), but the buttons in that XIB crash the app. The code for the buttons (IBOutlet & IBAction) are in SecondView.m.

Do I need to point the code from SecondView.m to FirstView.m? I tried using #import and @class... but was unsuccessful.

The code I'm using is completely valid... I'm pretty sure the issue has something to do with the XIB being loaded into the UIView... and then possibly losing its connection to the implementation file. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

FirstView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstView : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *SecondViewPopUP;
    IBOutlet UIButton *openBTN;
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *SecondViewPopUP;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *openBTN;
-(IBAction)showPopUp:(id)sender;
```

FirstView.m

```
@synthesize SecondViewPopUP;
@synthesize openBTN

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    SecondViewPopUP.alpha = 0;

    // Add IncidentsViewController to view
    SecondView *SecondV=[[SecondView alloc] init];
    SecondV.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 262, 269);
    SecondV.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [SecondViewPopUP addSubview:SecondV.view];
    SecondViewPopUP.frame = CGRectMake(0, 76, 262, 269);
    [SecondV release];
    }

-(IBAction)showPopUp:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Stats Button was pressed");

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

    SecondViewPopUP.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

SecondView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *share_facebook;
    IBOutlet UIButton *share_twitter;
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *share_facebook;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *share_twitter;

-(IBAction)shareOnFB:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)shareOnTwitter:(id)sender;
```

SecondView.m

```
@synthesize share_twitter, share_facebook;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }

-(IBAction)shareOnFB:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Shared on FB");
    }

-(IBAction)shareOnTwitter:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Shared on Twitter");    
    }
```

Comment: Added... most of it is faked... I didn't want to copy all of my code... but its the important stuff.

Comment: try NSLogging the outlets for the buttons, make sure it's not nil

Comment: What is the line `[SecondViewPopUP SecondV.view]` doing? The method name is missing somehow, right? It would be helpful if you provide us with some more detail, like error logs.

Comment: They aren't logging as nil...The buttons are all connected in the Interface Builder section of Xcode.

Comment: Hey David... that was a typo... it is supposed to have addSubview in it. All fixed. I'll grab some error logs.

Comment: No error logs except for "sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)"... it crashes with "Thread 1: Program received signal: 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'."

Comment: The code I'm using is completely valid... I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the XIB being loaded into the UIView... but losing its connection to the implementation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `FirstView` (and presumably `SecondView`) is a `UIViewController` not a `UIView` so naming it "FirstViewController" would be much clearer. Views and view controllers are very different things.

Secondly you are adding a UIViewController's view as a subview of another view on the line "[SecondViewPopUP addSubview:SecondV.view];" That's not how UIViewControllers are expected to be used and the [UIViewController programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12) recommends against it for good reason.

> Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing all of the views in a single view hierarchy. In iPhone applications, the views in a view hierarchy traditionally cover the entire screen, but in iPad applications they may cover only a portion of the screen. The one-to-one correspondence between a view controller and the views in its view hierarchy is the key design consideration. You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy. Similarly, you should not use a single custom view controller object to manage multiple screens worth of content.

Finally if you were to post the error listed when your app crashes we would probably see that you are attempting to send `-shareOnFB:` or `-shareOnTwitter:` messages to an instance of "FirstView" which does not implement them because your nib bindings are not configured appropriately ie you set the File's Owner of the nib to be "SecondView" and then loaded it with an instance of "FirstView" as its owner. Impossible to say for sure without more data.

Comment: Thanks Jonah... you are right about the view controllers. Here's my question: How would you recommend I maintain good use? I want to have a popup appear (not covering the whole screen) once a button is tapped. What's the best way to populate that?

Comment: Also, after the crash, my console reads "sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all Current language: auto; currently objective-c (gdb)"... it also crashes with "Thread 1: Program received signal: 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'."

Comment: You can have a view which does not have it's own UIViewController instance to manage it. Just create a view (loading it from a nib with UINib if that's convenient) and add it as a subview. If you have controller level logic specific to that view the create a controller class for it but that controller can inherit from NSObject not from UIViewController. See the "Note:" in the linked section of the UIViewController programming guide.

Comment: Last question: If I load a view with a NIB, will that NIB still be connected to a view controller? Or will it stand on its own?

Comment: When a nib is loaded it attempts to establish any connections it contains. Those connections are usually to the File's Owner proxy and you determine which object if any will be the File's Owner when you load the nib. UIViewController's -initWithNibNamed:bundle: will pass the UIViewController as the File's Owner. UINib and UIBundle allow you to specify an object as the File's Owner when you load a nib.